# How to prevent React from re render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and am currently trying to create a todo list. Everything works fine, however, when I try to delete an item in the array, the whole page gets re-rendered.

Can someone please let me know where I went wrong? I just want to delete a specific item once the button is clicked and not re-render the whole page.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./todo.css";

class Todo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      task: "",
      taskList: []
    };
  }

  handleAdd = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      task: "",
      taskList: [...this.state.taskList, this.state.task]
    });
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      task: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleDelete = task => {
    console.log(task);
    const newtaskList = this.state.taskList.splice(task, 1);
    this.setState({
      taskList: newtaskList
    });
    console.log(task);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form className='App'>
        <div className='input input-group mb-3'>
          <input
            type='text'
            className='form-control'
            placeholder='Enter a task'
            value={this.state.task}
            onChange={this.onChange}
          />
          <button className='btn btn-primary' onClick={this.handleAdd}>
            ADD
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className='output' id='output'>
          <ul className='list-group'>
            {this.state.taskList.map((task, index) => (
              <li
                className='list-group-item'
                key={index}
                style={{
                  display: "flex",
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                  alignContent: "center"
                }}>
                {task}
                <div className='input-group-prepend'>
                  <button
                    className='btn btn-danger'
                    onClick={() => this.handleDelete(task)}>
                    Done
                  </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `e.preventDefault();` in the `handleDelete` function

Comment: Change this ```onClick={() => this.handledelete(task)}``` by ```onClick={(e) => this.handledelete(e, task)}```

Comment: re-rendering is a good feature to keep the app updated as state object updates. What is the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: It's not the re-render from react, it's the form submit that is refreshing the page

Comment: Just add `type` to delete button like `<button type="button"` to fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the comment you have a form in your template. If you click the button your form in the template get submitted which causes in a postback which is a page reload. So either you stop the submission of form<sup>*(1)*</sup> or change the type of the button to `type="button"`:

```
<button type="button"
```

The default behavior is `type="submit"`, so changing the type would resolve your issue.

---

<sub>*1. You don't have any form submit event.*</sub>

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid refreshing page when submit event occure then you should use `preventDefault()`.

If you want to disable whole page rendering in `React` and re-render only some parts of you page, you can use two solutions:

1. extra comparison with `prevProps` or `prevState` inside `componentDidUpdate` for class component:

   `componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
       if(prevState.taskList !== this.state.taskList) {
           // do your magic here
       }
   }`
2. `useEffect()` hook in functional component:

You can tell React to skip applying an effect if certain values haven’t changed between re-renders. To do so, pass an array as an optional second argument to useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    // do your magic here
}, [taskList]); // Only re-run the effect if taskList changes
```

More information about this kind of feature you can find in [official React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by form submit in your react component as mentioned in the comments, you should use [e.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default behavior for the button submit:

```
...
<button
  className='btn btn-danger'
  onClick={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    this.handleDelete(task)
  }}>
  Done
</button>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Splice removes an element by index and returns the removed element and it manipulates the original array after splicing.

What you need to do is to change the `handleDelete` function. First parameter of an event function is the event object. So pass it as the first parameter and bind any other params with it.

You can try this-

```
handleDelete = (e, index) => {
    console.log(index);
    e.preventDefault();
    const copyTask = [...this.state.taskList];
    copyTask.splice(index, 1); // Splice directly change the copyTask array.

    this.setState({
      taskList: copyTask
    });
  };
```

And also change this line-

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleDelete(e, index)}
```

First param is the `event` object. Then pass the index other than the item.

Answer (score 0):

1.You are using `form` element of html. And since you are using button inside it you need to add `e.preventDefault` else it would act like submit and refresh the page.

2.While passing params in `handleDelete` you are not passing `event` neither you are passing `index`. To use `splice` you need the `index` of the element.

3.In react, I would suggest to use `spread operator` that helps not to mutate the state.

So, please replace these two things.

```
handleDelete = (e , index) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { taskList } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      taskList: [...taskList.slice(0 , index) , ...taskList.slice(index + 1)]
    });
  };
```

and, while calling handle delete function use,

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleDelete(e, index)}
```

And, regarding re-render. React will always re-render the component if any state in that component is getting changed. Here, tasklist state is getting changed when you are deleting. So component is getting re-rendered.